# Unity WebGL: why using downloaded Mp3 or OGG file, audio can't be played?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I need to download audio (OGG, Mp3 or wav) from URL and play it.

In Editor is working fine, and also in stand alone build.

But not in WebGL build.. i got any error or (depends on format) this:

> Streaming of 'mpeg' on this platform is not supported
>   UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip:GetContent(UnityWebRequest)

My Code:

// Here audio is downloaded based on audioURL
...
      WWW data = new WWW(audioURL); yield return data;
            AudioClip downloadedClip = data.GetAudioClipCompressed(false, AudioType.OGGVORBIS) as AudioClip;
            if (downloadedClip != null)
            {
                _audio.clip = downloadedClip;
            }
...

```
    public void PlayAudio() {
        // Here clip is play
                if (_audio.clip != null && _audio.isPlaying == false)
                    _audio.Play();
                else
                    Debug.Log("Background music not present!");
                _audio.loop = true;
    }

To download clip i've used also (instead first code part):


     using (UnityWebRequest www2 = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(audioURL, AudioType.OGGVORBIS))
            {
                yield return www2.SendWebRequest();

                if (www2.isHttpError)
                {
                    Debug.Log(www2.error);
                    LogAdd(www.error, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    AudioClip downloadedClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www2);                
                    _audio.clip = downloadedClip;
                }
            }
```

For some reason, audio in webgl isn't played.

EDIT 1: When uploading MP3 , error (also in editor) is:

> Streaming of 'mpeg' on this platform is not supported
>   UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip:GetContent(UnityWebRequest)

Comment: Judging by the error, I'd guess that your file is not actually mp3 or ogg, but mpeg file format. I'm not sure _why_ streaming mpeg files isn't supported in webgl, but judging by that error you won't get it working. Have you tried it with a different audio file that you're **absolutely** sure is MP3 or OGG?

I'd suggest just exporting a file from something like Audacity to make sure you're definitely using the file format you expect.

Comment: I've tried to convert to mp3 to be sure, with no luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved upgrading to 2018.4.

Now it works with MP3 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Unity document mentioned the audio format should be natively supported by the browser, you can check the support state from this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Or simply use audio tag to check the file.

As I tested ago, ogg suits chrome and firefox, and mp3 suits safari

Answer (score 0):

"Mp3" is short for MPEG-3; and indeed, if you look at Unity's [AudioTypes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioType.html), it explicitly defines the MPEG AudioType as "MP2/MP3 MPEG."

So basically: try using a non-mp3 file.